# LED Amplifier output (PWM) to voltage

Tags: led, pwm

My experimental LED grow light strips don't seem to like PWM.

The current setup is this:

30A Meanwell (clone) PSU 24-27v

eDMX Artnet to DMX

https://dmxking.com/artnetsacn/edmx4-pro-din

30 Channel DMX->PWM Splitter

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32387978299.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2fra&spm=a2g0o.order_list.0.0.21ef1802ARDdyL

A series of High Speed 30A LED Signal Repeater/Amplifiers

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001217314051.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.571172d0Lg9ysN&algo_pvid=5fd257ae-46fe-4328-be92-feae396d3807&algo_exp_id=5fd257ae-46fe-4328-be92-feae396d3807-15&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000015332913174%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B5.86%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BNZD%3Bsearch-mainSearch

And directly into the COB strips connected 3 in parallel  (each strip is rated at max 27v 4A, but I run at 24v ~3A)

From a logical flow perspective we have:
ArtNet-> DMX -> PWM -> Signal Amplifier -> LED COB strip (~3A @ 24v)

Am sure the high speed LED amplifiers are stressing them - but all my control circuits assume PWM (i.e. Artnet->DMX->PWM etc.) so am looking at a circuit that can smooth the output before hitting the lights.

Appreciate this can be done with an LC (Inductor+ Capacitor), but each channel will be drawing around 9Amps at 24v so it's somewhat more than electronic levels.

Alternatively, I throw out the control circuits, and start over - in which case I'd want a series of low cost BUCK converters that can each handle around 4A @ 24v and be able to be controlled say with a 0-5v signal line or with the 24v PWM Signal line.

Apologies in advance - I'm an embedded software guy with a knowledge of electronics that makes me probably more dangerous than useful.

Welcome thoughts on a circuit/components.

Comment: Do you have a link for the lights you are using? Are you using PWM to modulate the brightness of the lights? I don't know much about grow lights, but if you are using LED-based lights then you are pretty stuck with PWM. LEDs requires a certain forward voltage to operate. Filtering the PWM would likely reduce the LED input voltage to below the forward voltage of the LEDs and then they won't work at all. 
Probably need more info about the lights you are using and what you are trying to accomplish here...

Comment: Most likely the LEDs use analog CC control so some analog CV  control voltage is required.  It is far easier to filter a high impedance CV signal from PWM than 4A

Comment: I am using raw 24v COB and SMD strips - no controlling.

Comment: The lights will work comfortably in a range of say 12-27v

Comment: I am getting a bit done with PWM.  The LED Amplifiers make the lights scream (in pain lol). Where as a dedicated buck will gently increase and decrease the available AMPs with no aggressive switching.  And I see that a good Buck is comparable with PWM in terms of efficiency.   

So ideally there is a buck converter that I can use with the existing PWM signal somehow for control. Or alternatively, smooth the PWM output somehow without costing/loosing too much.

Comment: @AndrewMcClure concerning efficieny: the LEDs will run less efficient when dimmed with PWM compared to constant current.

Comment: Thanks @SimSon that's exactly my concern.  PWM has become the overarching technology, but I am thinking it is hard on the lights (and as you say less efficient).  

A constant current controlled via BUCK should be cleaner.  

So my challenge is one of implementation.

I have a low current PWM control signal (24v), and also  a set of PWM amplifiers that take basically anything from 12-32v and amplify it based on this signal.

But I want to use either the low amp control output OR the amplified signal - and somehow get a constant current single voltage output with no modulation.

Comment: Basic circuit:

"What you need is called a low pass R/C filter. You can make such a filter by wiring a resistor to the PWM output, the other end to a cap and the other end of the cap to ground. Your smoothed analog output voltage will be from the junction of the cap and resistor and ground. The impedenance of your meter movement will effect the performance of the filter and you may have to play around with the values of the cap and resistor, try 5k ohms, 10mfd cap and see what you get. If you can't drive the movement full scale, try lowering the value of the resistor."

But at 4 AMPs?

Comment: The main advantage of PWM is that it's simple to interact with, but analog control is certainly superior in some aspects (no flicker, efficiency). Note that "PWM dimming" usually means that a **constant current** is modulated. An LED must never be driven with unregulated current from a constant voltage PSU. Please provide more information about your LEDs, driver and circuitry. "drawing around 12Amps at 24v" makes me wonder if your LEDs are treated as intended..

Comment: @SimSon  The LEDs I am using are basic Aliexpress COB strips rated at 24v with a max rating of 4AMPs @ 27 and 70 deg C.

Currently they are wired with 3 in parallel drawing some 9A max at 24v - and up until now driven with some low cost high speed LED amplifiers.

See: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32828043205.html

But as I said, am not happy with the effect of these amplifiers on the LEDs and want to shift to constant current.

So question is do I throw everything out and start again, or can I realistically add a resistor and capacitor inline to the output at the higher amps

Comment: I wouldn't trust that driver, beside being rated for 30A! If it outputs PWM it is completely unsuitble for your leds.

Comment: For the amount of power you have, I'd use one of those famous ACDC LED drivers which have a 0-10V/PWM control input.

Comment: Something like this perhaps? Constant current with PWM control?

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000341086776.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.668239ddf5Vvz5&algo_pvid=e5491b5e-a023-4075-ac63-e17adacf99a1&algo_exp_id=e5491b5e-a023-4075-ac63-e17adacf99a1-2&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000001399067559%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B2.06%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BNZD%3Bsearch-mainSearch

Except with 4000mA output - not 1200!

Comment: @SimSon  Thanks.  Do you have any links? If we are going ACDC, I'd need to ensure we had 24v output and could handle the AMPs, Any links?  Certainly an area to explore.  I sent a link to a low amperage PWM controlled constant current driver so if these exist at higher amps ....

Comment: The most important thing is the *current, not the voltage*! Put the LEDs in series and look for a PSU rated for 3A and a power of no more than 300W (if you have 3 COBs/stripes with 100W each).

Comment: @SimSon  That's not a practical way forward,  It would mean purchasing hundreds of dedicated 72v PSUs and I'd still need a way to control them.
I already have a multi channel PWM driver and set of grunty 24v PSUs,

It's just that my existing amplifiers are signal repeaters rather than constant current devices.   What I really need is a set of low cost bucks that can be driven via a PWM signal OR a simple way to smooth the output of the existing Signal Repeaters.

Comment: Have bought a bunch of these 25v 4A LC Filters to experiment with.  Every light would need one.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000515430811.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4693704759wHnB&algo_pvid=a5b10924-566f-46e6-97a8-613566d3ca0d&algo_exp_id=a5b10924-566f-46e6-97a8-613566d3ca0d-5&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000002553162313%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B1.01%3B-1%3B-1%40salePrice%3BNZD%3Bsearch-mainSearch

Comment: If you were planning this from zero, a MeanWell driver (ACDC) would certainly be the way to go (cost, efficiency, warranty, controllable via PWM/analog signal). Some of them have efficiency of up to 98%! It's unfortunate that you already have constant voltage PSU.

Comment: Those LC filters won't do much because you already have a driver that provides unsuitable current. You need a **constant current LED driver** providing max 4A that can work in the voltage range 24V-27V. Of course, there are DCDC ones if you want to use your existing PSUs. But at that amperage, I'd strongly recommend to have a single driver for each COB!

Comment: @SimSon  My PSUs are Linear Switched Power Supplies - same tech. as the Meanwell devices.  And they do have a small POT for fine adjustments.  But ultimately we need finer grained control between the color spectrum at the light level, not the PSU level - otherwise you'd have to buy PSUs for each spectrum.

Comment: @SimSon - not sure what you mean by "unstable current".  They are just signal repeaters / amplifiers.  They put out whatever I put in - which is a nicely controlled PWM signal.  If I filter this, it should give me what I need surely?  But ideally it would be nice to buy a device that puts out a steady DC but adjustable by PWM - and researching this, there are such devices, but I've not found them at the sort of AMPs I need.

Comment: Show me a datasheet of your PSUs, "linear switched power supply" means nothing in that context. Is is important - as I was trying to say - that they provide *constant/stabilized current*. That's what LEDs need. Not a steady DC *voltage*, but a steady DC *current*.

Comment: I wrote *unsuitable* current (not unstable, though the current must be stabilized). The driver you are using provides 30A, which is way too much. Surely it won't reach 30A because the voltage is too low, but it will probably have quite some output capacity, so the LEDs likely receive current pulses that are far higher than those average 9A you wrote.

Comment: @AndrewMcClure - Hi, There seem to be lots of information added in your comments, but unfortunately that's the wrong place. All important information (e.g. datasheets, links to the supplier's webpages, block diagrams of your existing & proposed configurations, constraints e.g. what things you are saying you must use, because you have already bought them etc. etc.) need to be edited into the question. Please can you do that ASAP? The long comment thread here is likely to be moved to a chatroom soon, as it has turned into a discussion and useful info has been hidden in the volume of text. Thanks

Comment: @SamGibson

Ok Sam, I just didn't want this suggestion that the PSU I was using were different from the Meanwell - It's the same circuitry effectively, basically Meanwell knock off clones.   They put out 30A at 24v and no matter how hard I drive the signal repeaters, I can never get much past 3A per AMP per light which is below their rated capacity - also the lights are cooled so  there is even less concern.

But I am still left with the issue of changing PWM to steady clean DC which has not really been addressed by anyone here - instead there is always this attempt to go down side alleys.

Comment: @AndrewMcClure - Hi, Sorry there's no point trying to explain anything to me about your question. I got lost in the comments where I needed to see more details & clarity around the PSUs, the overall design etc. (the lack of diagrams means all readers must mentally construct the design in our heads). Unfortunately it looks like you might be asking someone to do a "whole project design" for you - which would be off-topic as "needs focus" a.k.a "too broad". If you're *not* asking for that, then I don't see a *specific*, narrow question with enough detail of existing devices, constraints etc. :-(

Comment: @SamGibson It's actually a very narrow question. 

A) Is there a PWM controlled device that output constant current at a variable rate;  or B) Given the volts/amps, what would an LC filter circuit look like.

As for B, I have now found on Aliexpress off the shelf LC filters in a range of up to 20A - so this gives me something to try.   As for A) - then I can only hope someone reading this knows of such a device as I am yet to find one with the output Amps required.

Comment: @SamGibson  I have updated the question to include all existing components. However, the scope of the question remains the same with the two possible outcomes identified - failing this I need to start again from scratch with the PSUs and control systems, but this seems extreme.

Comment: @AndrewMcClure - Thanks for updating the question. However remaining problems include: (1) No wiring diagrams of what you have tried, on which you can label current / voltages etc. As I said, without that site members are having to make those images (perhaps wrongly & perhaps with some doubts and wasted time) in their heads. (2) Your "narrow questions" A & B are not listed clearly in the question text. I strongly recommend you add them, as currently the question is very "free form". (3) The lack of trustworthy datasheets from AliExpress sellers means a higher risk that claimed specs are wrong.

Comment: (continued) (4) Your question "A" sounds like an [off-topic](/help/on-topic) shopping/recommendation question || I can't force you to improve the question in those ways, of course, but IMHO the question still does not have the required details / clarity, so don't be surprised if the question gets "closed" (a.k.a "put on hold") pending clarification (or pending being made on-topic) and/or you may not get many answers, if site members feel the questions is still missing details or clarity etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using constant voltage LEDs, and they light up at 12V (meaning 4 diodes in series) but you're driving them at 24V with resistors, your setup is horrifically inefficient since only ~50% of your power is even going to the LEDs.  This is the reason horticultural lighting is virtually never constant voltage but rather constant current which does not require heating up resistors.  Unless you are not paying for electrical power or only planning to briefly use these, it is probably cheaper to start over with high efficiency, constant current lights as you are going to spend more money heating up resistors than it would cost to buy proper grow lights before long.

That said, if you want to solve this problem while keeping your existing lights, most constant current LED drivers (e.g. Meanwell HLG series) will have an option for PWM input, which they use to regulate the output current.  In this case you have a constant voltage strip, but  nothing stops you from putting your strips in series, getting a ~3A constant current driver, and then controlling the current with PWM.  You'll still be wasting a ton of power heating those resistors, but it will be slightly more efficient since you won't be running the LEDs at higher peak currents.

> I mean ultmately changing the PWM on a constant voltage is effectively the same as changing the current (except in my case I'd add a small inefficiency with filtering the PWM).

A constant current driver refers to a special type of power supply that measures its own current output and then adjusts voltage to hold that current output constant.  They are the most common way to power LEDs, and are used in most light bulbs, lighting fixtures and horticultural lighting because they are the most efficient way to drive LEDs.

If you take a constant voltage source and reduce its average voltage by PWM, the result is still a constant voltage source.  Such a source cannot (safely) be used to power a load that requires a constant current source because the required circuitry to measure and regulate current is missing. More information here: [LED drivers: constant voltage vs. constant current](https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/abacus/solutions/technologies/power/the-design-engineers-guide/constant-current-vs-constant-current-led-drivers/)

**Do not attempt to power individual LEDs or those that expect constant current drivers with a constant voltage source**, even if the diode does not blow up immediately (the most likely result), you could easily start an electrical fire later on when no one is around to notice.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Yes, the COBs run pretty hot and need cooling.  Quite wasteful.  I am planning to move to these Samsung SMD type lights and see that they have both 12 and 24v models - am hoping the 24v will be not be wasteful as you suggest.

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/high-CRI-90-samsung-smd-5630_60778861087.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normal_offer.d_image.2fd96ab17ZbBxK

Comment: @AndrewMcClure Don't waste your money on constant voltage strips, you're just paying to heat up resistors.

Comment: To be fair, I have measured the PAR values as a function of wattage, and the COBs I have are not too different from the fancier SMD variety.  But thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @AndrewMcClure At 24v I expect them to be about 1/3 to 1/4 as efficient as you should be aiming for, just based on the circuit and from where you bought them. Unless you have very cheap power, aim for a minimum efficiency of 
2.5 μmoles/joule, and be careful about trusting the numbers cited by questionable vendors online.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I've had a look at the Meanwell PSUs with PWM control.  

If I change to constant current SMD lights (i.e. say something like the LM562) and drive it with my LC filtered PWM output - am wondering how much less efficient that would be than going with a (relatively expensive!) PWM controlled Meanwell constant current driver.  I mean ultmately changing the PWM on a constant voltage is effectively the same as changing the current (except in my case I'd add a small inefficiency with filtering the PWM).

Hmmm. May need to experiment.

Comment: @AndrewMcClure That question does not make sense.  You cannot drive a constant current LED load with a constant voltage source, at least not if you want it to work.

Comment: @user1850497   Hmm. I have a good friend who uses exactly this approach with his constant current Samsung LEDs with no issue at all.  I mean ultimately how does a constant current PSU reduce current if not by reducing voltage or utilising PWM?  Am I missing some magic here?  If a light draws x Amps at y volts and you want to dim it, you either have to PWM the signal and maintain V, or you reduce V.  Ohms law?

Comment: @user1850497  So ultimately if I LC Filter a PWM signal I am changing the voltage - hence the current - as a function of the PWM.

Comment: @AndrewMcClure A constant current driver uses current sensing and a feedback loop to hold current constant.  Without that feedback loop you have a constant voltage power supply, which will not work.  Check google, there are tons of guides online to LED power supplies that explain how different types work.

Comment: Hi @user1850497 

Thought I'd give a quick update.

I wanted a DC -> DC converter rather than a dedicated PSU as my power source may be mains or renewable.

Ended up finding these that were marketed as handling 3A !@ 24v

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000858902267.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.0.0.4ba81802HeCOhA

But despite my lights drawing ~3A at 24v with a constant voltage PSU, connecting these in line only permitted the lights to draw 1A.

So a bit disappointing - really need a gruntier DC -> DC Constant Current driver that will give the lights equivalent amps.

Comment: @AndrewMcClure Since that is a step down converter, you must supply it with > 24V DC in for it to work as you intend.  I would try with a ~30V supply if you have not already.  In general though buying from AliExpress is not the best idea if you want things to perform as expected.  Buying a commercial LED driver might make more sense.

Comment: @user1850497  thx yes have been looking. Quality higher Amp DC -> DC drivers seem scarce or non-existent